# Why does the URL "stockoverflow.com" not point to "money.stackexchange.com"?

Tags: feature-request, suggestion

The idea can't be new, but I found no question mentioning it.

internic.net says it's a GoDaddy domain, so I guess they are just sitting on it until the cash rolls in. But maybe it's cheap, who knows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why should it? Why would Stack Exchange network administrators want to have one more domain to configure, renew, install TLS certificates for...?

And why would this site want to get a bunch of programming questions from the people who mistype "stackoverflow.com", see the familiar interface and go straight for "Ask Question" button?

Back in the days when Stack Exchange was only starting up, the idea was indeed to acquire a bunch of "clever" domain names for various sites: https://nothingtoinstall.com, https://crossvalidated.com and a few others. It was [quickly dropped](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/05/domain-names-the-wrong-question/) and nobody really uses those domains anymore; few people know about them.

Comment: This site was actually migrated/seeded from an SE 1.0 site "basicallymoney.com" and so I often still use that URL out of habit.